# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: python, python-requests, openssl, urllib

I'm working on a new build to improve performance over our current build. The os has changed from Ubuntu 18.04 to Fedora 34, and I'm converting a script to python3.

The new build has openssl version `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021`

The server I'm posting to is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)`

The server I'm posting to has openssl version `OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`

The server that I'm posting to will be replaced, along with an openssl upgrade. But that won't happen until covid allows us back into the office.
I'd like to bypass the increased security protocols in the meantime. Unfortunately, this area is very foreign to me.

I've read about modifying `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` to use MinProtocol = TLSv1.0 instead of MinProtocol = TLSv1.2. But I don't see anywhere to make this change in the file.

I used urllib.request and requests, with the same result...

```
data = json.dumps(pickle_post_data()).encode('utf-8')
#response = requests.post(U_REGISTRATION_POST, data=data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(U_REGISTRATION_POST, data, 20)
```

I've also tried several variations of the following...

```
#context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
#context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
#context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1')
#context.set_ciphers('ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL')
#ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
#ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

Regardless of what I try, I get the following failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1257, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1303, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1252, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1012, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 952, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1426, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1129)
```

Is there anything else I should be trying? I'll keep working with google, but any direction would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**:
I'm using python 3.9, and found this in the ssl documentation:

```
Changed in version 3.6: OpenSSL 0.9.8, 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 are deprecated and no longer supported. In the future the ssl module will require at least OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1.0.
```

I don't think I dare try to update openssl on the server for fear of breaking production... From what I read, I don't know if I should upgrade, if I'm even able to... I read that the security flaws were introduced in the later versions... Back to google...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you solved this !?

Comment: @MehdiBenmesssaoud I wasn't able to resolve this. I put this Fedora image on the back burner while I work on an Ubuntu image. Got really sick over the holidays and haven't put much effort into either image. Will pick up again tomorrow.

Comment: I hope you have recovered. BTW, i have downgraded to Python 3.7 to resolve this issue. just using this for some old system tests. I think to make it work properly, the server's SSL version needs to be upgraded to a newer (proper) one.